# ssh into AWS EC2 instance with botocmdshell

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, paramiko

I have a cluster on AWS that I want to SSH into with `boto.cmdshell`. however maybe I'm not understanding the parameters to pass.

The node has the user `ubuntu` and no passphrase set.

```
ssh_client = sshclient_from_instance(instanceobj,
                 ssh_key_file =r'C:\Users\Neil\Downloads\sparkcluster.pem',
                 user_name ='ubuntu')`
```

I get this error when I run the code:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Neil/.ssh/known_hosts'`

This error makes no sense to me :/, I thought I am supposed provide the pem key to the `ssh_key_file` parameter. Am I missing something? I know sshing with putty works just fine.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What does ls -l ~/.ssh from a putty terminal show?

Comment: just provide a valid path to a the hostkey file or a blank file in `sshclient_from_instance(inst, host_key_file="path_to_file",...)` see https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/boto/manage/cmdshell.py. Note that this is the known_hosts file not your private key. just create a blank file if you do not have one.

Comment: @RodrigoM ls -l in .ssh shows, -rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1606 Jan 16 10:34 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1679 Jan 16 10:01 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  404 Jan 16 10:01 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2664 Jan 18 01:21 known_hosts

Answer (score 0):

From what I know and as per the [github code of boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/manage/cmdshell.py#L380), there is one more argument called `host_key_file` whose default value if not specified by the caller is `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. In your case, you don't have that file at your home directory `C:\Users\Neil`. Hence, you get this error.

**If you are connecting from a Ubuntu or linux based machine**

 Add the below lines at the end of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file :

```
Host IP_YOU_WANT_TO_CONNECT
     IdentityFile path/keyname.pem
     StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

or do this:

```
sudo touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts

ssh-keyscan -H [hostname],[ip_address] >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

In the first case, you may have to specify `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` as `host_key_file`. In the second case, the default argument value will work.

There is an equivalent option for windows as well. If you search, you can get lot of information. 
From what I know, you can install openSSH for windows and `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\etc\ssh_config` is the equivalent of what I posted above for windows. Fill in the information like above in that file. You can then specify this as the host_key_file.
I think you may also manually create a .ssh/ssh_config file in your home directory `C:\Users\Neil` and do something similar to ssh-keyscan I have done above for linux. But, I have never tried this.

Comment: I thought known_hosts is supposed to be in ur linux server not on m Windows Desktop?

Comment: there is no such thing. its just an ssh setting to allow ssh on particular hosts.You can check other questions related to known_hosts on windows on stackoverflow, superuser and serverfault.

Comment: also, even if you already have the file, pass the full path, C:\Users\Neil\.ssh\known_hosts